# css toggle button not changing class on first click but then delete it after function finishes running

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, togglebutton

I have a pure css toggle button, and i'm trying to change its state using javascript (jquery) everytime it is clicked. the problem is the first time i click on the button, the toggle doesn't change accordingly (class input:checked + .toggle-slider). in the debugger i saw it changes, but after the function block finishes running, suddenly the class input:checked + .toggle-slider is removed for some reason, and the only class it has is input:focus + .toggle-slider.
which makes the button look as if it was never clicked. after the first click and on the next clicks the class input:checked + .toggle-slider is finally shown.

the toggle button that has the problem is in a card div. i tried putting a similar toggle button not in a card, and it worked on first click. i wonder what prevents it from working the first time inside the div?

```js
$(".toggle-slider").click(checkToggleState);

function checkToggleState(e) {
  let checkbox = $($(e.target).siblings()[0]);
  if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
    checkbox.attr("checked", false);
    console.log("not checked")
  } else {
    checkbox.attr("checked", true);
    console.log("is checked");
  }
}
```

```css
.toggle {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 3.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
}

.toggle input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.toggle-slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: var(--card-shadow-color);
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.toggle-slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 1.3em;
  width: 1.3em;
  left: 4px;
  top: 8%;
  background-color: var(--body-bg-color);
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked+.toggle-slider {
  background-color: var(--toggle-on-color);
}

input:focus+.toggle-slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px var(--toggle-on-color);
}

input:checked+.toggle-slider:before {
  transform: translateX(1.7em);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">

  <label class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="toggle-slider"></span>
    </label>

  <span class="coin-title"><p id="${coin.id}">${coin.symbol.toUpperCase()}</p></span>
  <p>${coin.name}</p>

  <button class="btn">More Info</button>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet that I have added to your question to clearly show the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use jquery for that ? your `toggle-slider` is inside the `label` of the checkbox. So when you click on it, the checkbox automatically toggles the checked state ( like it would do if you clicked directly on it ). Just use css.
Or maybe i didn't understand your question ?

```css
.toggle {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 3.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
}

.toggle input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;

}

.toggle-slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: var(--card-shadow-color);
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.toggle-slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 1.3em;
  width: 1.3em;
  left: 4px;
  top: 8%;
  background-color: red;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked+.toggle-slider {
  background-color: blue;
}

input:focus+.toggle-slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px green;
}

input:checked+.toggle-slider:before {
  transform: translateX(1.7em);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">

  <label class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="toggle-slider"></span>
    </label>

  <span class="coin-title"><p id="${coin.id}">${coin.symbol.toUpperCase()}</p></span>
  <p>${coin.name}</p>

  <button class="btn">More Info</button>
```